# How to make an animated gif that shows each picture only once

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to make an animated gif with one second per picture that shows each picture exactly once. Here is a MWE:

```
from PIL import Image
import seaborn as sns
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make three random heatmaps and save them as "pic0.png", "pic1.png" and "pic2.png".
# You can use any three pictures you have instead.
for i in range(3):
    new_list = [random.sample(range(80), 10)]*6
    sns.heatmap(new_list)
    plt.savefig("pic"+str(i)+".png")
    plt.clf()

# Add the images to a list
images = []
for i in range(3):
    images.append(Image.open("pic"+str(i)+".png"))

# Create the animated GIF. I was hoping loop=1 would show each image once but it doesn't.
images[0].save("out.gif", save_all=True, duration=1000,loop=1, append_images=images[1:])
```

The result of this is the following:

[image]

- How do I make it show each image exactly once? Currently it shows them all twice.

Comment: Try: `images[0].save("out.gif", save_all=True, duration=1000, loop=1, append_images=images[1:])`

Comment: @Rotem How is that different from what I have?

Comment: `images[1:]` instead of `images[:1]`

Comment: Interestingly, with Microsoft photos it displayed 3 images and stops, but in Chrome it displays each image twice.

Comment: @Rotem oh sorry that was a typo. Fixed now

Comment: @Rotem they show twice using eog in Linux too.

Comment: AFAIK not all browsers/viewers handle the loop count the same way... see here https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/#loop

Answer (score 2):

According to the [following post](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4575) it's a known bug in Pillow.

> loop=1 actually loops twice!

---

We may use [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) CLI instead of Pillow:

```
import subprocess as sp

...

sp.run(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-r', '1', '-i', 'pic%1d.png', '-vf', 'split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse', '-loop' '-1' 'out.gif'])
```

---

The FFmpeg command is based on the [following answer](https://superuser.com/a/556031/635712).

- `pic%1d.png` Uses all png files that ends with one digit - consider storing the PNG images in a "clean" foder.
- `-r 1` Sets the frame rate to 1fps
- `-loop -1` Applies no looping

---

Updated code sample (assume FFmpeg CLI is in the executable path):

```
from PIL import Image
import seaborn as sns
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import subprocess as sp

# Make three random heatmaps and save them as "pic0.png", "pic1.png" and "pic2.png".
# You can use any three pictures you have instead.
for i in range(3):
    new_list = [random.sample(range(80), 10)]*6
    sns.heatmap(new_list)
    plt.savefig("pic"+str(i)+".png")
    plt.clf()

# Add the images to a list
images = []
for i in range(3):
    images.append(Image.open("pic"+str(i)+".png"))

# Create the animated GIF. I was hoping loop=1 would show each image once but it doesn't.
#images[0].save("out.gif", save_all=True, duration=1000, loop=1, append_images=images[1:])

# Use FFmpeg CLI instead of using Pillow
sp.run(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-r', '1', '-i', 'pic%1d.png', '-vf', 'split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse', '-loop', '-1', 'out.gif'])
```

---

[image]

---

A cleaner solution is writing the images to stdin pipe of FFmpeg subprocess:

```
from PIL import Image
import seaborn as sns
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-y', '-r', '1', '-f', 'image2pipe', '-i', 'pipe:', '-vf', 'split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse', '-loop', '-1', 'out.gif'], stdin=sp.PIPE)

# Make three random heatmaps and save them as "pic0.png", "pic1.png" and "pic2.png".
# You can use any three pictures you have instead.
for i in range(3):
    new_list = [random.sample(range(80), 10)]*6
    sns.heatmap(new_list)
    #plt.savefig("pic"+str(i)+".png")
    plt.savefig(p.stdin, format='png')  # Write image to stdin pipe of FFmpeg subprocess.
    plt.clf()

p.stdin.close()
```

---

We may also try using [matplotlib animation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/simple_scatter.html).

Comment: The solution seems to be to simply miss out the loop parameter!

Comment: What do you mean "miss out the loop parameter"? The loop parameter is `-1`. Isn't it working?

Comment: Just don't use loop at all. It turns out the default is what I need.